# C can't assign values from optarg

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

**The issue I am currently having**:

It seems like I can't assign a value from `optarg` to another variable.

I have never faced such an odd behavior where I can't assign values from one variable to another.

inner_config = optarg;

Values after the assignment:

```
optarg = 0x60003a9d5 "debug_config.conf" <char*>
inner_config  = 0x0 "" <char*>
```

Mind the problem is in the comments of the code segment.

**Code Segment**:

```
static char* inner_config = NULL; // Global var
static char* inner_log = NULL; // Global var
static char* inner_tee = NULL; // Global var

char option_config[PIPE_BUF] = {0}; // Global var
char option_log[PIPE_BUF] = {0}; // Global var
char option_tee[PIPE_BUF] = {0}; // Global var

static struct option const program_longopts[] =
{
  {"sanity", no_argument, NULL, 's'},
  {"pause", no_argument, NULL, 'p'},
  {"debug", no_argument, NULL, 'd'},
  {"tee", required_argument, NULL, 't'},
  {"config", required_argument, NULL, 'c'},
  {"log", required_argument, NULL, 'l'},
  {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
  {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};
    
int programcmd(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
//double seconds = 0.0;
  bool ok = true;
  char c = 0;

  initialize_main (&argc, &argv);
  set_program_name (argv[0]);
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain (PACKAGE_NAME, LOCALEDIR);
  textdomain (PACKAGE_NAME);

  initialize_exit_failure (PROGRAM_FAILURE);

  atexit (close_stdout);

  copyof_argc = argc;
  copyof_argv = argv;

  while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "spdt:c:l:", program_longopts, NULL)) != -1)
    {
      switch (c)
        {
        case 'c': {
            inner_config = optarg; // Printing the value of optarg shows the string value
// Assinging it to innerconfig fails, inner_config stays with a NULL address
            strncpy((char*)&option_config[0], inner_config, PIPE_BUF - 1);
        }break;
        case 'l': {
            inner_log = optarg; // Printing the value of optarg shows the string value
// Assinging it to inner_log fails, inner_config stays with a NULL address
        strncpy((char*)&option_log[0], inner_log, PIPE_BUF - 1);
        }break;
        case 't': {
            inner_tee = optarg;// Printing the value of optarg shows the string value
// Assinging it to option_tee fails, inner_config stays with a NULL address
            strncpy((char*)&option_tee[0], inner_tee, PIPE_BUF - 1);
        }break;

        case 's': {option_sanity = 1;}break;
        case 'd': {option_debug = 1;}break;
        case 'p': {option_pause = 1;}break;

        case_GETOPT_HELP_CHAR;
        case_GETOPT_VERSION_CHAR (PROGRAM_NAME, AUTHORS);
        default:
          program_usage (); break;
        }
    }

  if (!ok)
      program_usage (EXIT_FAILURE);

  return exit_status;
}
```

**Dummy code** that i have tried that also resulted in crashing :

```
static char *
strncpy2(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) // optarg is NULL here
{
    size_t i;
// BUG HERE : src (optarg) is turned to NULL address here,
// While having the current string address in the previous function.
   for (i = 0; i < n && src[i] != '\0'; i++)
        dest[i] = src[i];
    for ( ; i < n; i++)
        dest[i] = '\0';

   return dest;
}
// Part of the previous function from the segment above here : 
   case 'c': {
// optarg address is valid here : 
   strncpy2((char*)&option_config[0], optarg, PIPE_BUF - 1);

   }break;
```

**What have I tried**:

1. Reading the documentation optarg/getopt_long family function.
2. Debugging as well as setting dummy functions to emulate such behavior.
3. Searching on Google as well as stackoverflow (Most related bugs are regarding the syntex of long_options as well as case/switch handling, I don't think that's the issue here).

**My Environment**:
Compiler : gcc 4.8 (cygwin)
Runtime - CYGWIN_NT-6.1 1.7.25
Debugger : gdb

What causes this problem?

Comment: Try: `inner_config = strdup(optarg)`

Comment: Can we get the dummy functions emulating the behaviour instead of your real code?

Comment: I am sorry sir but as mentioned, The value can not be passed or assigned, string duplicate is getting optarg as NULL for some reason, As mention above.

Comment: Added the dummy function, It can be located below the code segment and above "What have i tried".

Comment: What is `option_config` here? Also, is this C, or C++ that you're using. Also check to ensure 'optarg' is not a macro of some sort. For example if you drop down into `gdb` you will be printing the _symbol_ `optarg`. If it's wrapped somewhere as a macro GDB won't notice it. To better debug this, have a simple function return `optarg`, e.g. `static const char *get_optarg(void) { return optarg; }`

Comment: 1.)option_config is a global variable character array with the size of "pipe_buf" set my <limits.h> 2.)Working in C obviously, for C++ we have std strings, But i am not using it. optarg is : char *optarg; "getopt.c" and declared as : extern char __declspec(dllimport) *optarg; /* argument associated with option */ INSIDE_CYGWIN in file "getopt.h"

Comment: Why `strncpy((char*)&option_log[0], inner_log, PIPE_BUF - 1)` and not `strncpy(option_log, inner_log, PIPE_BUF - 1)` ?

Comment: I have tried both, The reason for this action is because i was afraid it was some sort of a casting issue, and it wasn't. (still not a casting issue here it seems)

Comment: Did you try with local variables to check if the behaviour reproduce ?

Comment: Also, try to compile without optimization. Another simple thing might be that you are passing the same option twice on the commandline, and it's being overwritten by the second mention which somehow yields a NULL value. I suggest you manually pass/assign to `argv` to be sure

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names (and links) for the same thing.  There are a lot of function calls in your code that should be extraneous to reproducing the problem.

Comment: That is actually quite helpful, Thank you, Noted, And thanks to everyone who tried to help, I have managed to figure out the issue and resolve it as well as document it in the original post.

Comment: Note that your calls to `program_usage()` are inconsistent.  That the code compiles probably means you have incorrectly declared `extern void program_usage();` instead of the probably correct `extern void program_usage(void);`.  In C, the two declarations are radically different.  The first means `program_usage()` exists and returns no value but nothing is known about its argument list (except that it is not a variadic function); the second means the function exists, returns no value and takes no arguments. Or maybe you didn't declare it at all, but you should declare all functions before use.

Comment: Huh, How about that? here is the declaration (that i had to omit, Because it had nothing to do with the issue at hand): void program_usage (void) { ... } THIS -> program_usage (EXIT_FAILURE); shouldn't be valid, but the GCC compiler didn't say anything with "-Wall" option on, How about that... hmmm